# How do I copy all files from RestKit into my project?

Tags: xcode, restkit

I am having an issue with adding RestKit to my project in Xcode.  I have downloaded it and when I drag the RestKit.xcodeproj file into my Project Navigator, I get just the one file, not the whole package with folders for "Code", "Network", etc.  I have successfully added it RestKit to projects before the same way, but now it isn't working.  Re-downloading RestKit is a workaround I've used, but I shouldn't have to do that for every project I make.  How can I make sure all of the RestKit files come into my project?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the solution to my own problem.  If anyone else ever has this issue, just try closing and reopening Xcode.  When I did that, the files for RestKit came into the project that had the RestKit.xcodeproj file.